# Azure Search and elasticsearch-py

Tags: python, elasticsearch, azure-cognitive-search

now I am trying to test Azure Search with the official elasticSearch-py API. 
Unfortunately I can not find any example to test Azure Search with this API.

Someone has already faced this problem with the official API?

Comment: I think the question should be reopened: pi-2r is expecting Azure Search to behave as an Elasticsearch cluster, but it just doesn't because AS doesn't support the API. The question is phrased as "I cannot find an example" because pi-2r incorrectly assumes she/he did something wrong, but it's not really a request for a tutorial. See the answer by Trent Swanson. Maybe pi-2r should mention "Azure Search doesn't seem to honor Elasticsearch API" in the question to clarify that.

Comment: HI,
in order to respond to this and to the needs of a conference for Microsoft , I have developed a python SDK to poll Azure Search .
If you are interested , I invite you to use and / or enhance the SDK https://github.com/pi-2r/pyazuresearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work, although the Azure Search service utilizes Elasticsearch in the back end it does not expose the Elasticsearch API.  That said, the Elasticsearch SDKs and tools like Kibana will not work with it out of the box.

You can either access the REST API
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn798935.aspx

...or one of the other options to get Elasticsearch on Azure:

- Facetflow Elasticsearch from Azure Marketplace
- Deploy Elasticsearch to Virtual Machines (This is what I use)
- List item Deploy Elasticsearch to Cloud Services